# Matplotlib won't work in python even though i pip installed it

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, python-packaging

I'm trying to use matplotlib to do some plotting.

i wrote:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

When I try to run the program I get:

```
    import matplotlib as mpl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

This shouldn't be happening as I've pip installed matplotlib to the latest version (3.5.1) and matplotlib shows up correctly when i write "pip list" in the terminal.
Why doesn't matplotlib work?

Comment: Can you please share the output of the command `pip freeze` in your working directory ? Btw, are you using a *virtual environment* ?

Comment: when i write ```pip freeze``` i get:

```matplotlib==3.5.1```
along with my other packages. I am not using a virtual enviornment.

Comment: Check if you have multiple versions of Python installed, and also check that the name of the Python script being run is not called "matplotlib.py"

Comment: @DavidG i checked with ```py -0``` and it looks like I have two older versions (3.9-64 and 3.8-64). The Python script is not named "mathplotlib.py"

Comment: I also want to add that the same is for BeautifulSoup/bs4. I have installed it but i get No module named "bs4"

Comment: Try `python -m pip freeze`  Almost certainly your default python is different than your default `pip`.

Comment: @JodyKlymak I mean when I do that i still see the correct version of matplotlib there. Is there anything spesific I should look out for?

Comment: Hold on - it says that i'm using python 3.9.9 which is outdated. I have installed the latest version. Why hasn't it changed?

Comment: Which OS are you working with and how did you install the newest version of python?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I am using Windows 10. I installed the newest python version through downloading the latest version from the Python website.

Comment: It seems like the problem is that pip is using an older python version (it is using 3.9 while I use 3.10.1). How do I change that? When I run ```py -V``` I get ```pip 21.3.1 from C:\Users\johan\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)```

Comment: Easiest fix would probably be to simply uninstall the other python. You can also use `python -m pip` to use that pip that is associated with `python`. Other options can be to edit your PATH environment variable so that the newer python has preference.

Comment: @FlyingTeller I just did uninstall the older python version, but pip is still using 3.9. Should I try to uninstall and reinstall pip?

Comment: You should use Anaconda and not try to hand install

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you messed up your Python installations. Maybe `pip` installs something in one Python, but `python` calls another version, which doesn't have the libraries you want.

To get sure you're installing and running with the same Python, replace `python -m pip` with `python[version] -m pip`, and `python my_file.py` with `python[version] my_file.py`. For example, to use Python 3.9, use `python3.9` instead of `python`. And so on.

With this, you get sure to install and run things with the same Python. Also, it's good to try virtual environments, instead of fighting with global installations.